# can I set memory size in R?

Tags: r, memory, out-of-memory, logistic-regression, multinomial

I'm running this model:

```
library('nnet')
test <- multinom(events ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7 + X8 + X9 + X10 + X11, data = data)
```

And I got this error:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 313.3 Mb

Is there a way to fix this? For example is there somewhere in R that I can set memory, like the "setmem" in Stata? Thanks!

Comment: how big is your data? `dim(data)`

Comment: @fishtank  dim(data) shows "1870000    50"

Comment: Maybe you can just load the 12 columns you need (events,X1 to X11) into R instead of all 50 columns to save some memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the memory limit and extend max number of your R by following commands:

```
memory.limit()
# set max memory usage is 2G
memory.size(max=2000)
```

Case like this as Jenny's comments

```
memory.size()
#[1] 104.15
memory.limit()
#[1] 7888
a <- matrix(0, ncol=5000, nrow=5000)
memory.size()
#[1] 296.07
memory.size(max=8000)
#[1] 8000
memory.limit()
#[1] 8000
memory.size()
#[1] 297.23
b <- matrix(0, ncol=10000, nrow=10000)
memory.size()
#[1] 1059.07
```

Comment: ... if you are on Windows.

Comment: @Patric If memory.limit() shows 3000 then it means max is 3000Mb? When you set max = 2000 does that mean 2000 Mb? Just want to clarify on the units. Thanks!

Comment: @JennyShu, yes, 3000 is 3000M and about 3G.

Comment: @Patric Let me clarify. If I did "memory.size" I get 2000, then "memory.limit()" returns 3000. Then I did "memory.size(max=3000)", and then typed in "memory.size" again, and it is still  showing 2000. Did I change things or not? Thanks.

Comment: @JennyShu Yes, you changed the upper bound. `memory.size` tell you how many memory you already used so you type two times and get the same value. Try to allocate more memory after you increased the upper bound.